# For a fantasy draft program on java, how would I load the data from a text file into a list of separate ArrayLists?

Tags: java, list, object, collections, arraylist

I'm just starting, and I'm having a hard time loading this text file into different `ArrayLists`. The "------" obviously breaks each separate role. I wanted to create a class of `Roles` and create instances for each one, but I still haven't figured out how it works properly. Also, would creating a `List <Role>` be better than `List <ArrayList<String>>`? I know this is a basic problem, but I just can't figure it out after hours of working with it. Thanks!

```
Leader
1   Superman    DC
2   Captain America Marvel
3   Professor X Marvel
4   The Shoveler    Mystery Men

Brawn
1   Hulk    Marvel
2   Wolverine   Marvel
3   The Thing   Marvel
4   Beast   Marvel
5   Thor    Marvel
6   Mr. Furious Mystery Men
7   Mr. Incredible  Pixar

Gadgets
1   Batman  DC
2   Iron Man    Marvel
3   Spiderman   Marvel
4   Green Lantern   DC

Female Influence
1   Wonder Woman    DC
2   Jean Gray   Marvel
3   Emma Frost  Marvel
4   Rogue   Marvel
5   Elastigirl  Pixar

Bad Guy
1   The Joker   DC
2   Magneto Marvel
3   Lex Luthor  DC
4   Dr. Doom    Marvel
5   Riddler DC
6   Syndrome    Pixar
```

Comment: May you post what you already did? I don't think that anybody will solve your problem. We want to help you achieve your goal, not solve your problem for you.

Comment: Please show us the code that you have already written.  If you don't, we can't figure out why you are having a "hard time" with this seemingly simple problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it.

Make a class that holds an integer, a string and a string. Let's call it Person.

Now, your data structure will be `HashMap<string, ArrayList<Person>>`

Have a string for the name of the list you are currently populating, ListName.

Have an `ArrayList<Person>` for the list you are currently populating, ListContents.

Iterate over the lines of the file.

1) If the line is blank, skip

2) If the line doesn't start with a number, we are starting a new list - insert ListContents (if it is not empty) into the hashmap under the key ListName, set ListName to this line's contents (e.g. "Brawn") and make ListContents a new, empty ArrayList.

3) If it starts with a number, then split it using a regex, String.Split or whatever you like (hopefully you can split it on tabs, otherwise it would take an impossibly smart program to figure out when the spaces belong to the name and when they start belonging to the continuity!!), parse the first value as an int, and make a new Person out of these values, inserting it into the current list.

Now we have one list of people for each header, and every list is indexed by its header title in a hashmap.